# In spring-boot app, how to load static content (image for example) into jsp from local folder instead of resources folder?

Tags: spring-boot, static

I'm trying to load an image into jsp page from my local system folder which is on desktop. But in spring-boot, the image gets loaded only if it's put into resources folder. How to resolve this issue?

I already tried the below code from https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-static-resources, but no luck.

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry
      .addResourceHandler("/files/**")
      .addResourceLocations("file:/opt/files/");
 }
```

I had error saying

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Circular view path [error]: would dispatch back to the current handler URL [/error] again. Check your ViewResolver setup!
```

My folder set up is as follows:
Only the images in resources/static/img are getting loaded into jsp and I want the images present on the desktop to be loaded. Please help.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to this. This can be done by using a property which goes into the application.properties file

```
spring.resources.static-locations=file:PATH OF THE FOLDER
```

For instance if the project folder is located on desktop then it will be something like this

```
spring.resources.static-locations=file:/Users/sandeepamarnath/Desktop/
```

In the HTML OR Jsp page, the complete path can be given to the static files like CSS,JS, and Images

Comment: can you show how do you refer it in the page ? for example ```<img src='/static/foldername/file.jpg' />```

Comment: You can use like this

 ***<img class="logo" src="../myapp/flightapp/src/main/resources/static/css/img/logo.png" alt="My Logo">***

myapp folder is in Desktop, and the path till Desktop has been defined in the application.properties

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure little bit more. First resource handler then viewresolver

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class MvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/test/**")
                .addResourceLocations("file:D://tmp2/");
    }

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return viewResolver;
    }
}
```

this is a running example in win10 you need to change the path addResourceLocations accordingly. here you can find the project https://github.com/ozkanpakdil/spring-examples/tree/master/spring-boot-jsp dont forget to check out pom.xml. in order to run jsp in spring boot. Needed some extra provided dependency embeded jasper there.

Comment: Hi ozkan, thanks for the answer and I will try that. But I've given the View Resolver in application.properties file as we usually do in spring-boot. So do you think its necessary to still implement this view resolver here as you have shown?

Comment: well in my tests I focused on more how to include external folder and did it with that java configuration. if you figure out to do it with application properties feel free to share :) good thing about spring boot its so automatic and elastic I think you can find a way to do it with properties file.

Comment: I found the way to do it with application.properties file in spring-boot. You can use this property

spring.resources.static-locations = /Users/sandeepamarnath/Desktop/projectFolder